# Unusual matrix-vector notation and order of operations

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

So while I'm reading Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimization I've seen enough of the weird notations in matrix-vector form, but this one I just can't explain why that is the case. So on page 220 there's this dual function:
$$L(x,v) = x^TWx\ + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(x_i^2-1) = x^T(W+diag(v))x - 1^Tv$$
Here $W$ is a symmetric matrix and $x$ is an unknown vector, $v$ is also an unknown vector which is a lagrange multiplier. $x_i^2 - 1$ is simply a constraint on original problem i. e. $x_i^2 =1$, $1^Tv$ is simply a dot product between vector filled with $1$'s and vector $v$.

What I don't understand is how you go from $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i(x_i^2-1)$ to $x^T(W+diag(v))x$ and how in the world did we went from vector $v$ to diagonal elements of a *matrix* $v$? Btw as far as I understand it $diag(v)$ means diagonal entries of a matrix $v$.

I thought about interpeting it this way: $x_i^2 = x^Tx$, then $x^TWx + v^T(x^Tx-1) = x^TWx+v^Tx^Tx-1^Tv$, but I still don't understand how you could just sneak the $v$ in-between the $x^Tx$, make it a matrix with diagonal entries and still get the same result. Simple computation of these two cases results in two different answers: $v^Tx^Tx$ is simply vector $v$ multiplied componentwise by all quadratic terms from $x^Tx$; $x^Tdiag(v)x$ results in a function that looks like this $x_1^2v_1+x_2^2v_2+x_3^3v_3$ which is different from the first case $(v_1*[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2], v_2*[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2], v_3*[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2])^T$.

Comment: $\operatorname{diag}(v)$ denotes the $n \times n$ square matrix whose diagonal elements are the values $v_1, \dots, v_n$. Everything else here is just by linearity and definitions.

Comment: $\mathrm{diag}(v)$ is the matrix with zeros off the diagonal, whose diagonal entries are the coordinates of $v$.

Comment: I know, that's what I assumed was going on. But I don't see how a scalar function is equivalent to a vector as I have shown in the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^T x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ not $x_i^2$. Your intrepretation is not equal to the original sum.